# Is it possible to cache partials somehow without explicit cache block definition in every view/partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The only way i know to cache partials is (in general)

```
<% cache do %>
   <div> partial content </div>
<% end %>
```

but i am looking for a solution (gem, monkey-patching, .., anything reasonable) when i could define dynamically what i want to cache on controller side or during partial definition, for 
example:

```
# some controller

render 'expensive_view', cache_if: some_custom_logic_for_true_or_false

# or view

<%= render partial: 'expensive_partial', cache_if: some_custom_logic_for_true_or_false %>
```

In fact, i have a lot (~100) partials looking like this

```
# current partial content

<div> partial content </div>
```

and every of it can be cached or not depending on runtime business logic.

The boring way is to refactor every view with something like this:

```
<% cache_if some_custom_logic_for_true_or_false do %>
   <div> partial content </div>
<% end %>
```

but i am lazy and so - looking for some fun here...

Answer (score -1):

**view1.html.erb**

```
<%=render partial: 'caching_partial', locals: {condition: value, partial_name: 'partial_name', cache_key: 'cache_key'}%>
```

**_caching_partial.html.erb**

```
if condition
<% cache 'cache_key' do %>
  <%=render partial: "#{partial_name}"%>
<% end %>
else
 <%=render partial: "#{partial_name}"%>
```

**condition**: can be any valid condition according to your case

**partial_name**: would be the actual partial which need/dont need to be cached

**cache_key**: the cache key unique for that cache.